# how to export access tables to XML in access vba

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export XML file from Access table,I Created code that is used to convert the access table to .txt file ('$' delimited),can I change this code to convert the access table to .XMl or I need to code again for this,
I have following code:

```
sSql = ""
sSql = "SELECT * from tbl_exportFile where Upload_date=cdate(#" & Format(CDate(txtToDayDate), "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "#)"

If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
rs.Open sSql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If FE.FolderExists(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\") = False Then
       FE.CreateFolder (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\")
    End If

    F_Name1 = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\" & strReportFileName & ".txt"

    Set TSWrite = FE.OpenTextFile(F_Name1, ForWriting, True)

    strData = ""
    strData = strData & "noOfShippingBills$"
    strData = strData & "noOfInvoices$"
    strData = strData & "exportAgency$"

    TSWrite.WriteLine strData

    Do While rs.EOF = False
        strData = ""
        strData = strData & IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields![noOfShippingBills]), "", rs.Fields![noOfShippingBills]) & "$"
        strData = strData & IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields!noOfInvoices), "", rs.Fields!noOfInvoices) & "$"
        strData = strData & IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields!exportAgency), "", rs.Fields!exportAgency) & "$"
            TSWrite.WriteLine strData
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop    

    TSWrite.Close

    DoCmd.Hourglass (False)

    MsgBox "Export file Report Generated Successfully.", vbInformation, "RBI Macro"
Else
    MsgBox "Data not found to generate Import file Report.", vbInformation, "RBI Macro"
    DoCmd.Hourglass (False)
End If
```

please help me, thanks in advance !!